# Unable to get list of pages for a user using graph apis

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm calling the following API:

[https://graph.facebook.com/100071187141253/accounts?access_token=[token]](https://graph.facebook.com/100071187141253/accounts?access_token=%5Btoken%5D)

According to the documentation in here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/

It should return a list of pages but it returns an emtpy list. What's wrong? I have a page... why isn't the api returning it?

EDIT

These are the permissions my token has:

user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location, user_likes, user_events, user_photos, user_videos, user_friends, user_posts, user_gender, user_link, user_age_range, email, read_insights, publish_video, catalog_management, gaming_user_locale, user_managed_groups, groups_show_list, pages_manage_cta, pages_manage_instant_articles, pages_show_list, read_page_mailboxes, ads_management, ads_read, business_management, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments, instagram_manage_insights, instagram_content_publish, publish_to_groups, groups_access_member_info, leads_retrieval, whatsapp_business_management, instagram_manage_messages, attribution_read, page_events, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_posts, pages_manage_engagement, public_profile

Comment: Did you grant the necessary permission?

Comment: I can see all the permissions being granted when I inspect the token, included pages_show_list and business_management

Comment: Try and remove the permission, and then grant it again. There is a selector for which of your pages you want to allow access to in the login dialog, make sure the page is selected there.